# How to limit download/upload speed for all applications on CentOs 6.7?

Tags: linux, centos

Are there any ways to limit Download/Upload speed for all applications on my Server?
I want to limit Download/Upload speed at rate 50MB/s.

I have used WonderShaper to do that but it is not works properly, Upload speed is 50 MB/s but Download speed is always at 10MB/s (I have set the same values for both)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may try https://github.com/mariusae/trickle. It unlikely will work with java applications, but work good to me for others which use standard glibc calls.